# Android 13 - multiple notifications issue

Tags: android, notification

We're seeing an issue with multiple notifications on Android 13. Previous Android versions are working fine.

##### Repo steps

1. Send 2 push notifications to a device
2. Tap on one of the notifications
3. Kill the app
4. Tap on the remaining notification

**Result** - Nothing happens, the notification is not dismissed, and no action happens

##### Environment

- SFMC SDK 8.0.8 & 8.0.9
- Device Samsung A51 & S10

#### Docs followed

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

This is a sample of how the `PendingIntent` is created:

```
        val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        } else {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        }

        return NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(
            R.drawable.<some icon>,
            { context, notificationMessage ->
                val url = notificationMessage.url

                // Needed for multiple notifications
                val requestCode = Random().nextInt()

                if (url.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        requestCode,
                        Intent(context, SomeActivity.class).apply {
                            action = "SomeAction"
                        },
                        flag
                    )
                } else {

                    // Handle link
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context,
                        requestCode,
                        Intent(context, SomeOtherActivity.class).apply {
                            action = "SomeAction"
                            putExtra("url_key", url)
                        },
                        flag
                    )
                }
            },
            null,
        )
```

We have tried different flags for the `intent` associated with the `pendingIntent` but the behavior is always the same:

```
flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

*Note:* We are not seeing this issue with notifications created using the Firebase messaging sdk. We even copied the associated `pendingIntent` method, but this still has the same issue:

```
            { context, notificationMessage ->
                // Needed for multiple notifications
                val requestCode = Random().nextInt()

                val url = notificationMessage.url

                val intent = Intent("SomeAction").apply {
                    setPackage(context.packageName)
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        // Handle link
                        putExtra("url_key", url)
                    }
                }

                // Handle link
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    requestCode,
                    intent,
                    flag
                )
            }
```

Comment: I repeated these steps exactly as described and everything works as expected, however, I do not have your Samsung devices. I can tell you that in all cases where customers have previously had this complaint they were handling their own notifications and either not using a unique notification identifier or calling `cancelAll` on the PendingIntent(s). And when I say, "in all cases", that's been twice in 8 years. :)

Answer (score 0):

From Android S, the flag should be update to:

```
    val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
    } else {
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }
```